# Failed to upload blob(s) - Failed to fetch through the Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azureportal

I'm receiving an error when just trying to upload a file into a container in Azure, using the portal. It seems the UI for uploading files changed a bit, so I'm a little inclined to believe the problem may be due to an update, but I just wanted to be sure and see if there's anything I can check or do on my end. Tried a couple different files that I've uploaded, before today, successfully- they errored out as well.

Would anyone know why I'd suddenly be receiving this error?

> Failed to upload 1 out of 1 blob(s):
> blob_test.xml: Failed to fetch

Comment: I also got the same error before. I don't know the root cause. There is too little information from Azure, but refreshing the page or logging in again solves my problem. It might be a problem with Azure.

Answer (score 2):

Waiting even for five minutes didn't help me but refreshing the page did

Answer (score 2):

A combination of the two worked for me. refreshed the page + wait for a little while before clicking on upload

Comment: Unbelievable. This worked. What a joke (not you, Azure). Thanks for posting!

Comment: I don't know what to say. I spent so much time thinking it was something to do with the file. Facepalm!

Comment: You are the messiah, fml for working with Azure.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this also.  It seems like the upload button is enabled too soon.  If I select a file or files then press upload right away it often fails.  If I wait 10-20 seconds after the upload button is enabled it seems not to fail.

Comment: Even I experienced the same issue and @JackT Answer is helpful that I waited for 30 seconds because I uploaded 100's of files to the container, it uploaded successfully.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to upload to the container level (root folder) it will fail with an error " Failed to fetch". You need to **create a folder** than upload files into it

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with the browser. Try updating the browser and check again.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the following steps:

- Logout my account
- Login back
- Upload it back (It will work now✅✅)